# How do I change a vertical split layout inside a section to be Horizontal split on mobile

Tags: html, css

The two sides are under a section which is xop-container, the split is vertical, however I cannot seem to get the media query to work by turning the vertical split into a horizontal split for the mobile view.

```
<section class="xop-container">
    <div class="xop-left">
        <div style="text-align: center; background-color:#fcc567; margin-left:20%;margin-right:15%;">
            <p style="font-size:14px; display:inline-block; padding-left:30%; text-align:left;">Lumeca (Pty) Ltd is an<br/> electrical wholesaler.<br/> We supply industries, contractors and<br/> households with electrical<br/> products and equipment required for<br/><br/>

•   Power lines construction and maintenance<br/>
•   High, Medium and Low voltage electrification<br/>
•   Lighting<br/>
•   Cables<br/>
 <br/>
We are a Level 1 BBBEE contributor
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="xop-right">
        <div style="text-align: center; background-color:#fcc567; margin-left:20%;margin-right:15%;">
            <p style="font-size:14px; display:inline-block; padding-left:30%; text-align:left;">Lumeca (Pty) Ltd is an<br/> electrical wholesaler.<br/> We supply industries, contractors and<br/> households with electrical<br/> products and equipment required for<br/><br/>

•   Power lines construction and maintenance<br/>
•   High, Medium and Low voltage electrification<br/>
•   Lighting<br/>
•   Cables<br/>
 <br/>
We are a Level 1 BBBEE contributor
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The CSS has properties of the container, the left and right div

```
.xop-container {
    display: flex;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.xop-left {
    background-image: url(../images/city.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.xop-right {
    background: url(../images/country.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    width:100%;
}
```

Media query is for the mobile view, which I did for two views, but neither is working.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 400px) {
    .xop-left {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .xop-right {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 750px){
    .xop-container .xop-left{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .xop-container .xop-left{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I have tried two types of media query and they are both not working. where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `display:flex` to `display:block` and it works fine. Try this media query.

```
@media (max-width: 750px){
    .xop-container {
      display: block;
    }
    .xop-container .xop-left{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .xop-container .xop-left{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `display: flex` for `xop-container` even inside the media query, then in the main css set `flex-wrap: nowrap` and then `flex-wrap: wrap` in the media query (both of these on `xop-container`).

So, main css (apologies for the formatting, I'm on phone):

`.xop-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}`

Then in the media query:

`.xop-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}`

BTW here is a great writeup on flex box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/